# How to create multiple stackNavigator?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

Hello I'm trying to create:

- A top Bar for all screen
- a bottom bar for only 4 screen

So I have 2 screens -> Home screen and connection screen (without any top or bottom bar)

Then I have my 6 screen A B C D E F

I want a top bar on each and a bottom on A B C F

```
const TabRouter = createBottomTabNavigator(
{
  HomeAfterLoginScreen: { screen: A },
  ShowListAlertScreen: { screen: B },
  ShowListProfessionScreen: { screen: C },
  MyAccountScreen: { screen: F }
},
{
  tabBarPosition: "bottom",
  tabBarOptions: {
    style: { backgroundColor: "#50bcb8" },
    showIcon: true,
    showLabel: true,
    gesturesEnabled: true,
    indicatorStyle: { borderBottomWidth: 3, borderBottomColor: Style.color },
    inactiveTintColor: "#fff",
    activeTintColor: "#fff",
    tabStyle: { justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }
  }
});

const Router = createStackNavigator({
  // If I add A B C F here i loose my bottombar
  D : {
    screen : D, 
    navigationOptions: {(nav option ..)}
  },
  E : {
    screen : E, 
    navigationOptions: {(nav option ..)}
  },
  Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen,
    navigationOptions: {(nav option ..)}
  },
  App: {
    screen: TabRouter,
    navigationOptions: {
      visible: false,
      header: null
    }
  },
  ConnexionScreen: {
    screen: ConnexionScreen,
    navigationOptions: {(nav option ..)}
  },
});

export default Router;
```

There is a sample of my router.js

With this configuration I have bottom bar but I don't have my top bar. Any advice?

this is my screen A and i want a top bar on it. but if if add this screen on creatstack navigator i loose my bottom bar.
[image]

Comment: by 'top bar' you mean the header? Where you can add the buttons to the left and right and also a title to the page you are in?

Comment: Yes i mean the header

Answer (score 1):

```
const STANDARD_NAVIGATION_OPTION = {
  backtitle: null,
  headerStyle: { backgroundColor: 'green' },
  headerTintColor: 'white'
};

const App = createBottomTabNavigator({
  tabA: {
    screen: createStackNavigator(
              {
                tabAFirstScreen: {
                  screen: tabAScreen,
                  navigationOptions: {
                    ...STANDARD_NAVIGATION_OPTION,
                    title: 'Header Title A'
                  }
                }
              },
              { headerMode: 'screen' })
  },
  tabB: {
    screen: createStackNavigator(
              {
                tabBFirstScreen: {
                  screen: tabBScreen,
                  navigationOptions: {
                    ...STANDARD_NAVIGATION_OPTION,
                    title: 'Header Title B'
                  }
                }
              },
              { headerMode: 'screen' })
  }
}, {
  tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
    tabBarOptions: {
    labelStyle: { fontSize: 12 },
      activeTintColor: 'yellow',
      pressColor: 'orange'
     }
})

const MainNavigator = createAppContainer(App);

export default MainNavigator;
```

The idea is, first you have a `bottomTabNavigator` as root, then within the bottom tab, define each and every tab: `tabA`, `tabB` and so on..

Within each of the tab, define their own `createStackNavigator`, so that each and every tab will gives you the `header` look, which allows you to stack the screen within the tab too.

Answer (score 0):

An image of what you are expecting would help. Its a weird navigation pattern to hide the tabs on some screens , that means that you don't want the user to navigate to the hidden tabs. But if you are still using the same screens in the top tabnavigator, then i'ts pretty useless to have a bottom and top tabbar for the same screens.

You can have a tab with only 3 tabs, one of them being a nested tabnavigator with 4 tabs , that's the pattern.

Ok, you wan't a header ? , i thought you wanted top tabs navigation, then it's pretty easy, instead of passing a screen to HomeAfterLoginScreen, use a nested stacknavigator , because the tabnavigator doesn't give access to headers , but if you nest a stacknavigator there you can have a header. then you just remove the header with header:null

Comment: i add an image to explain

Answer (score 0):

try by removing the header: null line in

```
App: {
screen: TabRouter,
navigationOptions: {
  visible: false,
  header: null
}
```

Comment: i have a header but it's the same header for all the page :/ even if i set a title on each different page.

Comment: if i remove header: null my header appear the image shows the app with header: null

Comment: So now you want different header for each of these four bottom tabs ??

Comment: yep and i don't know how to do it

Comment: for that just do the same you did for D and E. Give seperate navigationOptions to all four screens in createBottomTabNavigator({})